# how to move the WooCommerce Add to Cart button below the product description

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to move the WooCommerce "Add to Basket" / "Add to Cart" button below the product description and extra form fields added by WP Field Factory @ [this page](http://www.thesmallbusinesslounge.com.au/product/business-ignition-consultation/).

I've tried the following in `functions.php` without success:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 50 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in functions.php

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try changing button position directly from summary hook like this, because even if you succeed this way, your button might be placed somewhere out of the form which will break your functionality.

Rather than this, you could just modify template files from `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/` folder.

Comment: what if theme updated in parent?

Comment: As far as the parent theme does not break the site/functionality, you're good. That's the beauty of creating a child theme. You can't control theme updates.

Comment: i heard that updating the theme will overwrite the function.php code. I cant code in my child theme's file. it is taking down the site

Comment: Updating parent theme will not remove child theme's code. Troubleshoot the error you are getting with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the description is part of the Tabs section as usual we can try to move the description tabs around the page. Try the below code in your functions page.

```
function move_product_tabs_override() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
 }
add_action('init', 'move_product_tabs_override', 5);
```